# RXJS: How do I add new values to an ovservable after creation?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Im working through the basics of observables [here][1]

The examples here show Observasbles as functions with multiple returns e.g.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 
const foo = new Observable(subscriber => {
  console.log('Hello');
  subscriber.next(42);
  subscriber.next(100); // "return" another value
  subscriber.next(200); // "return" yet another
});
 
foo.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});

// outputs 42, 100, 200
```

Question: Is it possible to add new values to an observable AFTER it has been created e.g. something like this pseudo code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 
const foo = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(200);
});
 
// this is pseudocode so wont work, but is the basis of this post.
...

foo.next(400);

...

foo.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});

// is it possible to output 200 and 400 by calling next after instantiation?
```

Or do I need to use a Subject to do that?

Comment: Yes use Subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Subject` for this. According to [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)

> **Every Subject is an Observer.** It is an object with the methods
> next(v), error(e), and complete(). To feed a new value to the Subject,
> just call next(theValue), and it will be multicasted to the Observers
> registered to listen to the Subject.

Observables do not have the `next` method so you can not pass values to them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`. But `BehaviorSubject` has an initial value, so you can try to do something like this:

```
var obs = new rxjs.Observable((s) => {
  s.next(42);
  s.next(100);
}); 
obs.subscribe(a => console.log(a));

var sub = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(45);
obs.subscribe(sub); 
sub.next('new value');
sub.subscribe(a => console.log(a));
```

Every `Subject` is `Observable`, so you can easily convert `Subject` to `Observable` via `yourSubject.asObservable()`.

**NOTE**: Don't forget to unsubscribe from observable in order to prevent memory leaks.